# Python tkinter invoke a new window from a existing window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have two windows in two separate files . The first file **login.py** contains login codes in which userName and Password are hardcoded . And the second window contains the main functionality of the application . i have included images of both windows [login.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6RQF.jpg) and [Main application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xy2w.jpg) . What i want is if the login credentials are correct it should destroy the login.py window and open Main appication window . And also is it good to make to separate files for two different windows or they should be in same file ?

**login.py** has this code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
logwin = Tk()
USERNAME = "Admin"
PASSWORD = "encdec"
logwin.geometry("320x240")
def logIn():
    username = userNameEntry.get()
    password = passwordEntry.get()
    if(username==USERNAME and password==PASSWORD):
        print("logged in")
    else:
        print("User Name or Password is incorrect")


#Gui starts here
userNameLabel = ttk.Label(logwin,text="User Name :")
passwordLabel = ttk.Label(logwin,text="Password :")
userNameEntry = ttk.Entry(logwin)
passwordEntry = ttk.Entry(logwin,show="*")
loginBtn = ttk.Button(logwin,text = "LogIn",command=logIn)
userNameLabel.place(x=40,y=70)
passwordLabel.place(x=40,y=110)
userNameEntry.place(x=110,y=70)
passwordEntry.place(x=110,y=110)
loginBtn.place(x=130,y=150)
logwin.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque i have added some code now , can you help ?

Comment: When ever the login is correct call logwin.destroy() inside the if case thus by destroying the login window.

Comment: And also place the code in same window but different window

Comment: @NeerajNair what do you mean by "place the code in same window but different window" ? Also you told to destroy login window but did't tell how to invoke my main application.

Comment: Sorry place the code in same py file but create a different 
for login and you can create 2 window in same code.If the login is correct then destroy that using destroy()